# Prove that the function have a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x^m - y^n$. Show that $f$ has a saddle point at $(0,0)$ if and only if both $m$ and $n$ are even.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When m and n crosses two the Hessian matrix becomes zero so we can not conclude anything from that. I am trying to prove it from the defination of Saddle point.